# Add custom action in easy admin

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

I have created a new action that allows to accept entities. The problem is the accept action button shows for all entites but I only want it to show for the inaccepted entites  not the accepted ones.
An accepted entity has the status 1 , the others status 0

here's my configue actions method
public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
{

```
    $accept_Deal = Action::new('accept','accept')
        ->linkToCrudAction('acceptAction');
       

    return $actions
        ->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, $accept_Deal)
        ->disable( Action::NEW, Action::EDIT)
        ->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::DETAIL)
        ->reorder(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, [Action::DETAIL, Action::DELETE]);
}
```

And my accept Action method

```
public function acceptAction(AdminContext $context){
    $id     = $context->getRequest()->query->get('entityId');
    $entity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Deal::class)->find($id);
    $entity->setStatus(1);
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($entity);
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
    return $this->redirect($this->get(CrudUrlGenerator::class)->build()->setAction(Action::INDEX)->generateUrl());

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in the doc , I don't know how i missed it

public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
{

```
    $accept_Deal = Action::new('accept','accept')
        ->linkToCrudAction('acceptAction')
        ->displayIf(static function ($entity) {
        return $entity->getStatus() == 0 ;
    });

    return $actions
        ->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, $accept_Deal)
        ->disable( Action::NEW, Action::EDIT)
        ->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::DETAIL)
        ->reorder(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, [Action::DETAIL, Action::DELETE]);
}
```